# Bootstrap col-sm-6 class not working on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am putting out products from sql table into `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 main_item_div mt-4 mb-4">` divs.

My problem is, that when i take a look at my page on mobile, the col-sm-6 class is not working, the products are always under each other, and not 2 div next to each other.

[You can take a look at my site on this link](https://projektar.hu/)

These divs are under the "Újdonságok, akciós termékek" title.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use col-6 instead of col-sm-6. Bootstrap is mobile-first. And you don't need an extra class col-md-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good day!

```
<div class="col-6 col-lg-3 main_item_div mt-4 mb-4"></div>
```

`col-sm` styles apply for viewport ≥ 576px, so you should use `col` in this case. Also, you need not both `col-lg-3` and `col-xl-3` classes, because bootstrap media queries based on `min-width` - so keep only `col-lg-3` for large displays.

Comment: Thanks, its okay now.